# rails button_to class change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4. And I try to give my button_to form a class:

```
          <%= button_to "unsubscribe",
                 :form_class => 'unsubscribe', 
                 :controller => :places, 
                 :action => 'delid',
                 :plid => subscription.place.id,
                 :method => :post %>
```

But the form class is "button_to"

Controller looks like this:

```
def delid
  @lolka = Subscription.where(user_id: current_user.id, place_id: params[:plid]).destroy_all
  @subscribed = Place.find_by_id(params[:plid])
  @subscribed.update_attributes(:subscribers_count => Subscription.where(place_id: params[:plid]).count)
  @subscribed.update_attributes(:subscribers_male => Subscription.where(place_id: params[:plid], user_gender: 'male').count)
  @subscribed.update_attributes(:subscribers_female => Subscription.where(place_id: params[:plid], user_gender: 'female').count)
  @places = Place.all
  redirect_to :back
end
```

maybe i'm doing something wrong? and it's better to use link_to? but how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to); `:form_class` (as well as `method`) goes in the *second* `html_options` hash:

```
<%= button_to "unsubscribe", {
             controller: :places, 
             action: 'delid',
             plid: subscription.place.id,
             }, {
             method: :post
             form_class: 'unsubscribe'
             } %>
```

Comment: worked for me. thanks. and value or other html options goes in the second?